# Dependency Cycle While Adding AuthInterceptor by Using Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

All dependencies before adding auth interceptor work fine. After auth interceptor it gives an error of error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle: Below codes show how I add all dependencies

I provide AuthInterceptor with OkHttpClient

```kotlin
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        authInterceptor: AuthInterceptor,
        apiConfiguration: ApiConfiguration,
        httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor?,
    ): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()

        httpLoggingInterceptor?.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        if (httpLoggingInterceptor != null) {
            okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        }

        okHttpClientBuilder
            .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(apiConfiguration.timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(apiConfiguration.timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
    }
```

How I provide AuthInterceptor

```kotlin
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAuthInterceptor(
        sessionManager: SessionManager,
        refresher: Lazy<TokenRefresher>,
    ): AuthInterceptor {
        return AuthInterceptor(
            sessionManager = sessionManager,
            refresher = refresher,
        )
    }
```

and how I provide RefreshToken

```kotlin
@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTokenRefresher(
        refreshTokenRepository: RefreshTokenRepository
    ): Lazy<TokenRefresher> {
        return lazy { TokenRefresher(refreshTokenRepository = refreshTokenRepository) }
    }
```

Binding RefreshTokenRepo

```kotlin
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindTokenRefresher(refreshTokenRepositoryImpl: DefaultRefreshTokenRepository): RefreshTokenRepository
```

Comment: What are bindings for RefreshTokenRepository and SessionManager?

Comment: I updated the question. Also I annotated the SessionManager class with @Singleton

Comment: @TheLibrarian I was importing the wrong library...

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong library. `dagger.lazy` must be used instead of `kotlin.lazy`